# What is the pin layout / labels of this oil gauge?

Tags: electrical, gauges, pressure, instrument

I have a veglia oil pressure gauge from a fiat coupe 16v. On the reverse of the clock is 4 pins, the top and left ones are labeled negative and positive respectivly, but can anyone tell me what the other 2 pins are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this diagram will help. This is for a Pantera, but it is a Veglia gauge. Don't pay any attention to the colors they mention, but everything else should be golden for you.

[image]

Comment: Does that just take 12v directly? Or should I drop the voltage a bit? I'm trying to make it work outside a car.

Comment: @ruffles - I'm assuming it does 12v directly ... but not sure.